# How to create a line chart which is based on aggregated and filtered data for a shiny dashboard?

Tags: r, filter, shiny, shinydashboard

So I recently started experimenting with shiny and I like very much. However, so far I had only very simple visualizations. Now I am trying to create a line chart which contains aggregated data (amounts=yaxis) and based on descrete values for the x-axis (YearsMon f.i. 201901).

So the idea is that i have a slider input where i can specify the range for the years and a filter which enables for me to filter the aggregated data for different categories.

A sample of the data set is provided below.

```
 Generation Amount Rating
 [1,] "201806"   "100"  "A"   
 [2,] "201807"   "200"  "B"   
 [3,] "201808"   "300"  "A"   
 [4,] "201809"   "200"  "B"   
 [5,] "201810"   "200"  "A"   
 [6,] "201811"   "100"  "B"   
 [7,] "201812"   "130"  "A"   
 [8,] "201901"   "400"  "B"   
 [9,] "201902"   "300"  "A"   
[10,] "201903"   "200"  "B"   
[11,] "201806"   "300"  "A"   
[12,] "201807"   "100"  "B"   
[13,] "201808"   "400"  "A"   
[14,] "201809"   "320"  "B"   
[15,] "201810"   "200"  "A"   
[16,] "201811"   "90"   "B"   
[17,] "201812"   "230"  "A"   
[18,] "201901"   "430"  "B"   
[19,] "201902"   "190"  "A"   
[20,] "201903"   "320"  "B"
```

So this is the following code I tryed:

```
Generation <- c(201806, 201807, 201808, 201809, 201810, 201811, 201812, 201901, 201902, 201903, 201806, 201807, 201808, 201809, 201810, 201811, 201812, 201901, 201902, 201903)
Amount <- c(100, 200, 300, 200, 200, 100, 130, 400, 300, 200, 300, 100, 400, 320, 200, 90, 230, 430, 190, 320)
Rating <- c("A", "B", "A", "B","A", "B","A", "B","A", "B","A", "B","A", "B","A", "B","A", "B","A", "B" )

df1 = cbind(Generation, Amount, Rating)


ui1 <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("slate"),
                       sidebarLayout(
                         sidebarPanel(
                           sliderTextInput(inputId = "range", 
                                       label = "Choose range", 
                                       choices = Generation, 
                                       selected = range(Generation), 
                                       grid = TRUE),
                           selectInput(inputId = "rat",
                                       label = "Chose the rating",
                                       choices = unique(df1$rating))
                         ),#sidebar panel
                         mainPanel(verbatimTextOutput("graph1")
                         )# closing main panel
                       )# closing sidebarlayout
)# closing fluidpage


server1 = function(input, output) {

  #interactive range
  my_range <- reactive({
    cbind(input$range[1],input$range[2])
  })

  #create the filter
  df_final <- reactive({
    filter(df1, between(Generation,input$range[1],input$range[2])) %>% 
      select(Generation,input$rat) 
  })



  # createn the aggregation 
  df_final2 = reactive({
  df_final() %>%
    select(Generation, Rating, Amount) %>%
    group_by(Generation) %>%
    summarise(sum_amount = sum(Amount))
  })

  # plot the graph 
  output$graph1 <- renderPlot({

    req(df_fianl2())

     ggplot(df_final2(), aes(x = Generation, y = sum_amount)) +
      geom_line(aes(colour = Rating)) +
      geom_point()
    })
}
```

So what I would like to see is basically a line chart. On the x-axis the Generation (YearMon) which can be filtered with the SliderInput.
On the yaxis the aggregated amount since the amount repeat themself multiple times in the same year. So I would like to see the total for the year in order to plot it.
Last but not least I want to be able to see the plot for rating A and rating B.

Unfortunetly, I still struggle with the reactivity concept and therefore, I dont know how exactly to make it reactive in this way.

I tryed looking up some solutions online but I found only one which I did not understand at all ([Line Chart Dashboard with Aggregated Data Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53308833/line-chart-dashboard-with-aggregated-data-points)). So any help is highly appriciated!

Comment: Use `plotOutput` instead of `verbatimTextOutput` if you want to plot something. Also you have some typos (`req(df_fianl2())` and `df1$rating`). You can delete `my_range` as it is not used anywhere. Also `df1` is a matrix currently. Use `data.frame` instead of `cbind` to create a `data.frame`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking [GyD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4509096/gyd)'s comment into account, here is a simple example. I have simplified your code and there is still room for improvement:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinyWidgets)

Generation <- c(201806, 201807, 201808, 201809, 201810, 201811, 201812, 201901, 201902, 201903, 201806, 201807, 201808, 201809, 201810, 201811, 201812, 201901, 201902, 201903)
Amount <- c(100, 200, 300, 200, 200, 100, 130, 400, 300, 200, 300, 100, 400, 320, 200, 90, 230, 430, 190, 320)
Rating <- c("A", "B", "A", "B","A", "B","A", "B","A", "B","A", "B","A", "B","A", "B","A", "B","A", "B" )

df1 = data.frame(Generation, Amount, Rating)


ui1 <- fluidPage(
    theme = shinytheme("slate"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderTextInput(inputId = "range", 
                            label = "Choose range", 
                            choices = Generation, 
                            selected = range(Generation), 
                            grid = TRUE),
            selectInput(inputId = "rat",
                        label = "Choose the rating",
                        choices = unique(df1$Rating))
        ),#sidebar panel
        mainPanel(plotOutput("graph1")
        )# closing main panel
    )# closing sidebarlayout
)# closing fluidpage


server1 = function(input, output) {

    #interactive range
    # my_range <- reactive({
    #     cbind(input$range[1],input$range[2])
    # })

    #create the filter and aggregation
    df_final <- reactive({
        df1 %>% filter(between(Generation,input$range[1],input$range[2]), Rating == input$rat) %>% 
            group_by(Generation, Rating) %>%
            summarise(sum_amount = sum(Amount))
    })

    # plot the graph 
    output$graph1 <- renderPlot({

        req(df_final())

        ggplot(df_final(), aes(x = Generation, y = sum_amount)) +
            geom_line(aes(colour = Rating)) +
            geom_point()
    })
}

shinyApp(ui1, server1)
```

**Update**

For question 1 from the comment below:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinyWidgets)

Generation <- c(201806, 201807, 201808, 201809, 201810, 201811, 201812, 201901, 201902, 201903, 201806, 201807, 201808, 201809, 201810, 201811, 201812, 201901, 201902, 201903)
Amount <- c(100, 200, 300, 200, 200, 100, 130, 400, 300, 200, 300, 100, 400, 320, 200, 90, 230, 430, 190, 320)
Rating <- c("A", "B", "A", "B","A", "B","A", "B","A", "B","A", "B","A", "B","A", "B","A", "B","A", "B" )
Test <- c(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1)

df1 = data.frame(Generation, Amount, Rating, Test)


ui1 <- fluidPage(
    theme = shinytheme("slate"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderTextInput(inputId = "range", 
                            label = "Choose range", 
                            choices = Generation, 
                            selected = range(Generation), 
                            grid = TRUE),
            selectInput(inputId = "rat",
                        label = "Choose the rating",
                        choices = unique(df1$Rating)),
            selectInput(inputId = "test",
                        label = "Choose the test",
                        choices = unique(df1$Test))
        ),#sidebar panel
        mainPanel(plotOutput("graph1")
        )# closing main panel
    )# closing sidebarlayout
)# closing fluidpage


server1 = function(input, output) {

    #interactive range
    # my_range <- reactive({
    #     cbind(input$range[1],input$range[2])
    # })

    #create the filter and aggregation
    df_final <- reactive({
        df1 %>% filter(between(Generation,input$range[1],input$range[2]), Rating == input$rat, Test == input$test) %>% 
            group_by(Generation) %>%
            summarise(sum_amount = sum(Amount))
    })

    # plot the graph 
    output$graph1 <- renderPlot({

        req(df_final())

        ggplot(df_final(), aes(x = Generation, y = sum_amount)) +
            geom_line() +
            geom_point()
    })
}

shinyApp(ui1, server1)
```

Notice how I added a Test column to df1 and both Rating and Test are in filter but not group_by.

For question 2 from the comment below:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinyWidgets)

Generation <- c(201806, 201807, 201808, 201809, 201810, 201811, 201812, 201901, 201902, 201903, 201806, 201807, 201808, 201809, 201810, 201811, 201812, 201901, 201902, 201903)
Amount <- c(100, 200, 300, 200, 200, 100, 130, 400, 300, 200, 300, 100, 400, 320, 200, 90, 230, 430, 190, 320)
Rating <- c("A", "B", "A", "B","A", "B","A", "B","A", "B","A", "B","A", "B","A", "B","A", "B","A", "B" )

df1 = data.frame(Generation, Amount, Rating)


ui1 <- fluidPage(
    theme = shinytheme("slate"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderTextInput(inputId = "range", 
                            label = "Choose range", 
                            choices = Generation, 
                            selected = range(Generation), 
                            grid = TRUE),
            selectInput(inputId = "rat",
                        label = "Choose the rating",
                        choices = c("A", "B", "A & B - one line", "A & B - two lines"))
        ),#sidebar panel
        mainPanel(plotOutput("graph1")
        )# closing main panel
    )# closing sidebarlayout
)# closing fluidpage


server1 = function(input, output) {

    #interactive range
    # my_range <- reactive({
    #     cbind(input$range[1],input$range[2])
    # })

    #create the filter and aggregation
    df_final <- reactive({
        if(input$rat %in% c("A", "B")) {
            df1 %>% filter(between(Generation,input$range[1],input$range[2]), Rating == input$rat) %>% 
                group_by(Generation) %>%
                summarise(sum_amount = sum(Amount))
        }else if(input$rat == "A & B - one line"){
            df1 %>% filter(between(Generation,input$range[1],input$range[2])) %>% 
                group_by(Generation) %>%
                summarise(sum_amount = sum(Amount))
        }else if(input$rat == "A & B - two lines"){ # this if isn't necessary but included for clarity
            df1 %>% filter(between(Generation,input$range[1],input$range[2])) %>% 
                group_by(Generation, Rating) %>%
                summarise(sum_amount = sum(Amount))
        }

    })

    # plot the graph 
    output$graph1 <- renderPlot({

        req(df_final())
        if(input$rat != "A & B - two lines"){
            ggplot(df_final(), aes(x = Generation, y = sum_amount)) +
                geom_line() +
                geom_point()
        }else{
            ggplot(df_final(), aes(x = Generation, y = sum_amount)) +
                geom_line(aes(colour = Rating)) +
                geom_point()
        }

    })
}

shinyApp(ui1, server1)
```

Notice how only the two lines option needs a colour parameter. Basically, the selectInput or radioButton just indicates the selection in the ui (you can rename these as you desire), the real work happens in the server. Again, I'm sure there are other ways of doing this but if you master the tidyverse functions you'll be able to manipulate the data as you wish.

Comment: Ah thank you so much ! This works. Just few question to improve my understanding. 1. If I would have more Filters which I would liek to use (besides the Rating,) then i Would add them all to group_by right ?
2. If I would use want to see the sum of A, B and A & B together, what would I have to do ? For instance if I use checkboxGroupInput - I can compare A and B as two seperate lines. But how could I make it that I have one line which contains only A or B or bother together?

Comment: 1. Not necessarily. Actually, I mentioned that there is room for improvement. Currently you could remove the Rating from group_by since you've already filtered to only include input$rat. The only reason I kept it is because you have aes(colour = Rating) in ggplot although that could be removed too. As long as you are filtering between particular features you do not need to group_by any besides Generation. 2. Following on from 1. if you would still have As and Bs in your data (2 lines) then you would need the group_by to contain Rating as this would be necessary for ggplot. See updated answer.

Comment: Let me know if the 2 updated pieces above make sense.